# Passing dynamic arguments to methods based on config mapper between methods and arguments

Tags: python, dynamic

Hi I have problem of passing dynamic arguments to different functions.

For example:

Lets say i have 7 variables (arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7 ) all are computed variables.

Now, I need to pass only arg1,arg2,arg3 variables to method1 , arg1,arg4,arg5 to method2 etc.

I need to do this dynamically.

Like having a mapper function between method and variables it can accept. And by selecting the method, I need to get the variables it can accept and pass only those variables to functions

```
def method1(arg1,arg2,arg3):
    pass

def method2(arg1,arg4,arg5):
    pass

def method3(arg1,arg2,arg4,arg6)
    pass
```

How to achive this ????

Answer (score 0):

Named parameters might be the solution you are looking for, as you can then pass a dictionary of named values to each method call.  For example:

```
# named arguments
args = {
    'arg1': 'One',
    'arg2': 'Two',
    'arg3': 'Three',
    'arg4': 'Four',
    'arg5': 'Five',
    'arg6': 'Six',
    'arg7': 'Seven'
}


# explicitly name the parameters, good for readability
def method1(arg1=None,arg2=None,arg3=None, **kwargs):
    print("arg1 %s arg2 %s arg3 %s" % (arg1, arg2, arg3))

# explicitly name the parameters, good for readability
def method2(arg1=None,arg4=None,arg5=None, **kwargs):
    print("arg1 %s arg4 %s arg5 %s" % (arg1, arg4, arg5))

# no named parameters, check the kwargs dict for each required argument
def method3(**kwargs):
    arg1 = kwargs.get('arg1')
    arg2 = kwargs.get('arg2')
    arg4 = kwargs.get('arg4')
    arg6 = kwargs.get('arg6')
    print("arg1 %s arg2 %s arg4 %s arg6 %s" % (arg1, arg2, arg4, arg6))

method1(**args)
method2(**args)
method3(**args)
```

Running that code produces the following output:

```
arg1 One arg2 Two arg3 Three
arg1 One arg4 Four arg5 Five
arg1 One arg2 Two arg4 Four arg6 Six
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply and this may be another view of solving the problem but i know some config or mapper of method to arguments mapping. As I will pass a method type which i want to call, the mapper should return me the variables and then i need to pass those variables(arguments) alone to that method..

Comment: I've added another answer, I'll leave this one here as it may be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a very basic example of how you might map the methods to arguments. It assumes the `args` is a `dict` that is inscope for `call`. You will probably need to pass your `args` as a parameter to `call`.

```
method_mapper = {
    method1: ('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'),
    method2: ('arg1', 'arg4', 'arg5'),
    method3: ('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg4', 'arg6')
}

def call(method):
    arg_names = method_mapper.get(method)
    if arg_names:  # we have args
        print("method is %s" % (method.__name__))
        print("  argument names are %s ; where" % (arg_names,))
        for name in arg_names:
            print ("    %s = %s" % (name, args.get(name)))

call(method1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried another way of doing it . Correct me if i am wrong in this approach

In a class , all the variables i had it in the init itself. You can compute or change the variables . Then After getting the method name, I will call the wrapper to get the variables need to be passed to the method and then will call the method with variables

```
class Class1():
   def __init__(self):
      self.arg1 = 0
      self.arg2 = 0
      self.arg3 = 0
      self.arg4 = 0
      self.arg5 = 0

   def compute(self):
       self.arg1 =1 
       self.arg4 = 1
       method_name = "cars"

       method_to_call = getattr(Class1(),method_name)
       method_variables = method_to_variables_mapper(method_name)
       result = method_to_call(method_variables )

       print result

   def method_to_variables_mapper(method_type):
      mapper = {
           "method1" : [{"arg1_name" : self.arg1} , {"arg2_name" :                  
          self.arg2}]
           "method2" : [{"arg3_name" : self.arg3}],
           "method3" : [{"arg1_name" : self.arg1}, {"arg3_name" :  
          self.arg3}] 
        }

     return mapper[method_type]

   def cars(self, *args)
       return 1

   def bikes(self,*args)
       return 2
```

Comment: There are a few mistakes in that code. You can use my answer and modify it to find the method and argument values introspectively like you try above for `method_to_call`.